# system.xml What is the difference in adding a new configuration option process for different option types (secret, file)?

Tags: magento2, system.xml

From the official M2 Developer certification guide I'm stuck at this question.

> How would you add a new system
>   configuration option? What is the difference in this process for different option types (secret, file)?

I know how to add new system configuration options but I have no ideea about this part  **What is the difference in this process for different option types (secret, file)?**.

Any clues,tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret is used for getting raw encrypted value

check below link for more detail

https://inviqa.com/blog/how-use-system-configuration-and-helpers-magento-2